# clear old AWS MediaPackage content from Live Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-live-streaming, aws-media-live, aws-mediapackage

I am using AWS MediaLive and MediaPackage to deliver a HLS Livestream.
However if the stream ends there is always one Minute available in the .m3u8 playlist.
The settings *"Startover window (sec.): 0"* does not seem to solve this.
Deleting and creating new .m3u8 playlist would be very inconviniert because all players would have to be updatet.

Do anyone have an advice?

Cheers, Richy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post.  If i understand correctly, you are referring to the MediaPackage endpoint which serves up a manifest with the last known segments, (60 seconds worth of segments by default).

There are several ways to alter or stop this behavior. I suggest testing some of these methods to see which you prefer:

[a] Delete the public-facing MediaPackage endpoint shortly (perhaps 10s) after your event ends. All subsequent requests to that endpoint will return an error. Segments already retrieved and cached by the player will not be affected, but no new data will be served.  Note: you may also maintain a private endpoint on the same Channel to allow for viewing + harvesting of the streamed content if you wish.

[b] Use an AWS CloudFront CDN Distribution with a short Time to Live (TTL) in front of your MediaPackage Channel (which acts as the origin) to deliver content segments to your viewers. When the event ends, you can immediately disable or delete this CDN Distribution, and all requests for content segments will return an error.  Segments already retrieved and cached by the player will not be affected, but no new data will be served from this distribution.

[c] Encrypt the content using MediaPackage encryption, then disable the keys at the end of the event. This Same approach applies to CDN Authorization headers, which you can mandate for the event playback and then delete after event completes.

[e] Use DNS redirection to your MediaPackage endpoint. When the event ends, remove the DNS redirector so that any calls to the old domain will fail.

I think one or a combination of these methods will work for you.  Good Luck!